# How'd Latin sum-mŏnĕo ("to remind privately") become modern English summon (authoritatively/publicly call up)?

Tags: etymology

This seems like an odd transition, from a private warning to a public and authoritative request. Does anyone have information on how and when that private-to-public transition happened? I've checked several online etymologies, and none gives more gloss.

[Latin meaning here (Lewis 1879)](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=summoneo)

Comment: The word came into Middle English via Old French, where it already had the meaning of a demand to appear for a legal proceeding.

Comment: This seems like an ideal question for the Law SE. It’s not clear to me that a summons in a criminal case is public, nor that serving papers in a civil case is public.

Comment: The french verb "sommer" and its derivative "sommation" appeared in the middle age and are still widely used in their legal sense (a formal notice).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not even about English. It seems to be concerned with a meaning shift in Latin or Old French

Comment: Okay, I'll post my questions about the etymologies of English words on another website next time